# Shapely intersection with multiple MultiPolygons where a percentage of Multipoloygons intersect?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I'm using Shapely's polygons for human-generated data. Multiple humans were asked to draw polygons around certain features in images. For each image, we thus have n `MultiPolygon`'s, where n equals the number of participants per image.

I can plot each of these `Multipolygon`'s.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for ii, multi_poly in enumerate(multi_polys):
    for poly in multi_poly.geoms:
        x,y = poly.exterior.xy
        plt.plot(x,y, c=colors[ii])
```

[image]

We can see that at some locations, the `Multipolygon`'s overlap, while at others there is no overlap.

I wish to get the overlap, or intersections, of these polygons.
This should be trivial, as I can do something like:

```
intersection = multi_a.intersection(multi_b) \
            .intersection(multi_c) \
            .intersection(multi_d) \
            .inters...
```

I can plot this intersection on the previous plot and we see:

[image]

This looks pretty good. However, this method only returns the regions where all `Multipoloygon`'s overlap.  Is there a way to get the intersection where 75% of the polygons overlap? Or where 50% overlap?

A code example: The following dummy data gives this figure:

```
P1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])
P2 = Polygon([(2.5, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2.5, 3)])
multi_a = MultiPolygon([P1, P2])

P1 = Polygon([(-1, -1), (-1, 2),(2, 2), (2, -1)])
P2 = Polygon([(3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4), (3, 4)])    
multi_b = MultiPolygon([P1,P2])  

P1 = Polygon([(-2, 4), (2.2, 4),(2.2, -2), (-2, -2)])
P2 = Polygon([(-1.5, 3), (-1.1, 3), (-1.5, -1), (-1.1, -1)])    
multi_c = MultiPolygon([P1,P2])

P1 = Polygon([(2.5, -1), (3.2, -1),(3.2, -2), (-2, -2)])
P2 = Polygon([(3, 0), (4, 0), (3, 1), (4, 1)])
multi_d = MultiPolygon([P1,P2])
```

[image]

On these four multipolygons, the intersection method would returns no intersection as there is not a single spot that all four multipolygons occupy. However, the blue square, accentuated with yellow marker, is occupied by the blue, orange and green polygon. Thus 75% of the multipolygons overlap at this location.

Is there a way (preferably using Shapely) to get the locations where 75% of polygons overlap?

---

The accepted answer appeared to break down in certain conditions.
I found the problem: the boundaries of the contain shape sometimes overlap the inter polygons. I can replace `if geom.contains(polygon):` with `if geom.contains(polygon.buffer(-1)):` and it works exactly as intended.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to split all geometries to get a flat list of non-intersecting regions on the XY-plane, and then see how many of the original geometries contain each region. Any region that is contained by at least some threshold number of the original geometries can be added to the result. This is easier to explain using a combination of code and illustrations.

To start with, we'll need to fix one issue. The example you put together has a couple invalid geometries, which will cause Shapely to throw an error when attempting to query spatial relationships (e.g., calling `contains` or `intersects`). You can check that using the `is_valid` property, and get a more detailed information by calling `explain_validity`:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.validation import explain_validity

P2 = Polygon([(-1.5, 3), (-1.1, 3), (-1.5, -1), (-1.1, -1)])

>>> P2.is_valid
False

>>> explain_validity(P2)
'Self-intersection[-1.3 1]'
```

Basically, it's not happy about shapes like these being expressed as a Polygon when they should be multi-polygons:

[image: Invalid shapes]

So to make your example valid, some of your multi-polygons will have 3 rather than 2 constituent polygons:

```
P1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])
P2 = Polygon([(2.5, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2.5, 3)])
multi_a = MultiPolygon([P1, P2])

P1 = Polygon([(-1, -1), (-1, 2),(2, 2), (2, -1)])
P2 = Polygon([(3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4), (3, 4)])    
multi_b = MultiPolygon([P1,P2])  

P1 = Polygon([(-2, 4), (2.2, 4),(2.2, -2), (-2, -2)])
P2 = Polygon([(-1.5, 3), (-1.1, 3), (-1.3, 1)])
P3 = Polygon([(-1.5, -1), (-1.3, 1), (-1.1, -1)])
multi_c = MultiPolygon([P1,P2,P3])

P1 = Polygon([(2.5, -1), (3.2, -1),(3.2, -2), (-2, -2)])
P2 = Polygon([(3, 0), (4, 0), (3.5, 0.5)])
P3 = Polygon([(3.5, 0.5), (3, 1), (4, 1)])
multi_d = MultiPolygon([P1,P2,P3])
```

Hopefully your real source data has valid geometries (or you have some way of converting them to become valid geometries - which incidentally is an upcoming feature in Shapely 1.8, implemented via [`make_valid`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#validation.make_valid), but it is not yet released), since otherwise the method described below will not work.

With that out of the way, the first step is to get a flat list of non-intersecting regions from your list of shapes. To do this, we start with the original list of intersecting shapes (note darker shading where multiple shapes overlap):

[image: Original intersecting shapes]

Convert them to lines using [linemerge](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.linemerge) (in combination with [unaryunion](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union)):

[image: Linework]

Then [polygonize](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize) the result:

[image: Polygonized]

It might not be clear from the picture, but the idea is none of these geometries intersect - some of these polygons have holes in them (in cases where one shape previously contained another). So this represents the "flat list of non-intersecting regions on the XY-plane" that I was referring to in the beginning.

The code for the process so far looks like this:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import linemerge, unary_union, polygonize

# Original shape definitions here (snipped)...

shapes = [multi_a, multi_b, multi_c, multi_d]

lines = unary_union(linemerge([geom.exterior for shape in shapes for geom in shape.geoms]))
polygons = list(polygonize(lines))
```

Next, we check each resulting region in the `polygons` list, and check how many shapes from the original list it intersected with. If it's above the threshold (defined here as `0.75 * len(shapes)`, then we add it to the result:

```py
threshold = 0.75 * len(shapes)

def overlaps(polygon, shape):
    for geom in shape.geoms:
        if geom.contains(polygon):
            return True
    return False

result = []

for polygon in polygons:
    containing_shapes = []
    for shape in shapes:
        if overlaps(polygon, shape):
            containing_shapes.append(shape)
    if len(containing_shapes) >= threshold:
        result.append(polygon)
```

If you're dealing with a large dataset, checking intersections in a nested loop like that can be quite slow (`O(N^2)`), so you can probably speed it up using an [`STRtree`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#str-packed-r-tree):

```py
from shapely.strtree import STRtree

# (Previous code here to get the flattened list of polygons...)

tree = STRtree([geom for shape in shapes for geom in shape.geoms])
result = []

for polygon in polygons:
    matches = [o.wkt for o in tree.query(polygon) if o.contains(polygon)]
    if len(matches) >= threshold:
        result.append(polygon)
```

Comment: Hi. This answer appears to be exactly what I need - however, when I apply it to my own data it doesn't work. I'm not sure if there is a problem on my end or on the solution side. I added a small section to my original question

Comment: I found the issue and added it to my original question